# How to use arrow characters in winforms

Tags: winforms, special-characters, excel-addins

I'm creating an excel add-in and i wanted to use up/down characters in a winforms form for a button's text.
I tried using ˄ and ↑ and ▲.
They all worked well on office 2010 (windows 7) but not on office 2007 (windows xp).
I'm obviously missing some basic understanding about the way these characters are used.

Any help would be welcome
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows XP has crummy fonts with poor support for unusual glyphs.  Use the Charmap.exe applet on the target machine to find a font and a glyph that works.  The poor man's choice is v and ^ (letter v and shift+6).  An image is another solution.  Ask more questions about this at superuser.com